# Error regarding ActiveAdmin in Ruby on Rails when customizing the menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion,
Ruby  1.9.2,
Rails 3.2.2,
Sass 3.2.3

Following this tutorial:
http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html

Following this video tutorial
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAxlrHcEg9U

I add the activeadmin gem, run bundle install, then run 
rails generate active_admin:install 
rails generate active_admin:resource POST

Only after creating the app/admin/posts.rb and trying to run either 
db migrate 
rails server

fails with the error

uninitialized constant Post NameError

with out that posts.rb file i am able to run the admin interface error free.

I tried moving the sass-rails gem out side of the :assets in my gem file and re-running bundle install as suggested in another question, but to no avail I still have the error

according to the getting started active admin tutorial "Post" is suppose to be a module name so i assume the code above is calling a class method (ActiveAdmin as the class, register as the method) and sending the module as a parameter and the block do end

Regardless the error is implying that RoR doesn't know what Post is. As if it does not exist. Being new to rails i do not know how to navigate well, meaning i do not even know where this ActiveAdmin source file is in order to dig through it for a method Post

Thank you for the consideration and your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked tutorial assumes that you have already created a model named `Post` (and have run `rake db:migrate` to link it to the database).  The purpose of the `rails generate active_admin:resource Post` command is to tell ActiveAdmin that you want it to consider the Post model in part of what it does.

Historically, you'll see models like Post and User in Rails a lot -- these are the commonly used examples of creating a blogging application (a user can create blog posts).

So, whatever models *you* have in your application can be registered with ActiveAdmin by replacing `Post` with the name of your model.

Another note: while generators like this tend to be forgiving, a Post is a model that is defined in `post.rb` and is linked to a SQL table called `posts`.  Be careful with things like upper- and lower-case, and singular and plurals.  In Rails they all fit together in a special way.

Comment: lol i quit ruby on rails 2 years ago and started up again 3 weeks ago, and this would have fixed my problem back then so i will give you credit for it. Or at least it sounds like an un-migrated model error.